# Promotion within the Chinese Communist Party for workers in the Civil Administration

Tags: china, chinese-communist-party

What are the requirements for promotion within the Chinese Communist Party? Specifically, can a talented junior Civil Administration official advance in the CCP while also progressing in their administrative role without engaging in significant Party activities?

Comment: Part why such one-party systems manage to be stable is the strong interlinkage between membership and good standing in the party and a successful career. That is a classic strategy and the CCP appears to follow it to the extreme.

Comment: Yes, trying to identify the institutional synergy between the bureaucracy and CP. Can you please refer any document which gives out the mechanics of this relation please.

Comment: documents about the internal operations (explicit and implicit) of the CCP... yeah, right