# How are members of the Communist Party of China assessed for promotion?

Tags: china, chinese-communist-party

How are party members promoted to a higher CCP appointment? Is there a system of periodic assessment by senior party officials?

Comment: These two questions seem very similar: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/62620/relation-between-communist-party-of-china-and-civil-admistration

Comment: The difference is one is bureaucracy and other is CPC leadership. They are two different in many countries. The Chinese synergy seems unique.

Comment: When everything else is equal, loyalty to the prevalent doctrine of the communist party and personal favoritism is the ultimate tie-breaker.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure there is a healthy share of insider’s politics, especially when considering the common purges in the name of ‘eradicating corruption’ taken to a whole new level by Xi Jinping but to a lesser extent by all 4 CCP leaders since Mao.

A big part of the answer since Deng Xiaoping has been simply the Economic performance of the area they were in charge of. More specifically GDP seems to have been used as one of the main indicators. The way we know this is the recent explicit shift enacted under Xi Jinping of asking his party members and local leaders to stop putting GDP growth above everything else like the environment, as well as his whole narrative of common prosperity.

Of course, even if you had strong economic performance, it wouldn't shield you from a purge as discussed earlier, nor being used as a scapegoat for any events in your region that caused a big enough outrage online that censors couldn’t keep up with.

I believe the recent shift from GDP as the main measure is bringing a lot of interest among China-watching communities to identify what will take its place. Contenders seem to be the development of any strategic industries (like microchips, aerospace, not social media apps nor video games)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than 90 million Party Members in China, not all of whom hold government positions. Some are university students, some are employed in private companies, and some are within the government bureaucracy as civil servants. There are no mandatory requirements for joining the Party to be in any of the positions mentioned above, but it certainly helps them getting promoted or some preferential treatment. Only government leadership positions, or party mechanism positions require Party Membership to be considered for appointment ([source](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/137483908333594965.html?qbl=relate_question_1)).

According to [this Party document](http://www.gov.cn/zhengce/2019-04/21/content_5384955.htm), there are four kinds of assessment: Regular assessment, occurring at each local Party Member Conference; Annular assessment; Task-specific assessment; and Per-term assessment. The assessments assess the work efficiency, work ethics, adherence to Party policy, Leadership ability, emergency response ability, and so on. The assessments are done by fellow Party Members within the facility, their superiors, and special envoys sent from the Central Organizational Department. The results of assessment determines whether the person is to be promoted, demoted, or fired.

(Note that this is the *official* policy; whether it is actually adhered to is another matter.)